# How to retrieve a secret value accessible only from a role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager, aws-roles

I need to access a secret coming from a different account from my user "X-app-pr-user", to the user is attached a role "cross-account-secret-read" that gives the permission to read the secret identified by ARN "arn:accountB-secretId", so I'm authorized to read the secret even though it's a cross-account request.

What I tried so far is to access the secret by doing the following while using the user "X-app-pr-user":

```
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id arn:accountB-secretId
```

But I receive the following error:

> An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetSecretValue operation: User: arn:X-app-pr-user is not authorized to perform: secretsmanager:GetSecretValue on resource: arn:accountB-secretId because no resource-based policy allows the secretsmanager:GetSecretValue action

Is there something I should do to retrive the secret? Like assuming the role when calling the get-secret-value command?

Thank you in advance

Comment: The resource policy of the secret needs to allow the user that you are using

Comment: ... or the account that you are using.  And then IAM can allow the user